# Add info window to placemarks

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, marker

I am using geoxml3 in order to parse kml files. My question is how am i able to extract description from the kml file for each placemark and place it in an info window?

Till now the following is my code:

```
function displayKml() {
        initialize();
        parser = new geoXML3.parser({
            map: map,
            processStyles: true,
            createMarker: addMyMarker,
            createOverlay: addMyOverlay
        });          
        parser.parse("Uploads/" + document.getElementById('<%= text2.ClientID %>').value); 
    }

     function addMyMarker(placemark) {
        // Marker handling code goes here
         parser.createMarker(placemark);

      }

      function addMyOverlay(groundOverlay) {
        // Overlay handling code goes here
        parser.createOverlay(groundOverlay);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

geoxml3 creates InfoWindows for the Placemarks by default in the default createXXX functions.  If you override them  you have to create the InfoWindows in your version if you want them.  I usually start by copying the code in the default function, then changing it appropriately.  It looks like you are using the default function, so I am not sure what behavior you are seeing and why you are doing that.  GroundOverlays don't have InfoWindows, none of the examples KML files you have posted so far contain "name" or "description" tags (but they do open InfoWindows for me).

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_IT_info_kmlB.xml

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_emptyKMLa.xml